# Best way to post data to a WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, winforms, wcf, wcf-security

I have a Windows Forms application (multiple installations, various clients) which need to post data regularly to a WCF Service. I plan on hosting the WCF service on a GoDaddy hosted website.

My question is what is the most secure way of posting this data? My main concern is making sure the data is not tampered with.

TIA.

Comment: Securing your transport channel using SSL and with good authentication mechanism should be enough to secure your data from being tampered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WCF secuity, mainly Transport and Message security. If interoperability with older ASMX clients and *extremely* good performance are not your main priorities but security is, then you should go with Message security, since it's the more robust of the two schemes in terms of security. Transport security will work well on an intranet but there are many hops that it will not account for over the internet. Message security will encrypt and sign every message with the user credentials, whereas Transport security secures your endpoints but your messages *can* still be tampered with when they are routed over the internet. In genral Message security is the advised method over the internet. Having said all that it is possible for your service to use *both* together, which I would assume means the best of both worlds.

I think the best choice in terms of security will be to use message security along with commercial SSL certificates (such as those sold by GoDaddy, Equifax etc.), it's relatively easy to secure your WCF enterprise with SSL certificates, lots of stuff online on how to do it. Furthermore you can make your service almost bulletproof reliable and ensure guanranteed delivery by [throwing MSMQ into the mix](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326909/Creating-a-WCF-Service-with-MSMQ-Communication-and).

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx#TransportSecurity) will be very helpful for you as well.